# System of linear equations with repeated equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Suppose that I have this over-determined system of equations,

$$a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_3x_3 = k_1$$
$$b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + b_3x_3 = k_2$$
$$c_1x_1 + c_2x_2 + c_3x_3 = k_3$$
$$d_1x_1 + d_2x_2 + d_3x_3 = k_4$$

Normally, if this system of equation can be constructed in matrix multiplication form as
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
d_1 & d_2 & d_3
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
k_1 \\
k_2 \\
k_3 \\
k_4
\end{bmatrix}$$

And this can be solved in a least-square sense. However, I have found in MATLAB that if I repeated the first equations for $n$ times, i.e.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
d_1 & d_2 & d_3
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
k_1 \\
k_1 \\
k_1 \\
\vdots \\
k_1 \\
k_2 \\
k_3 \\
k_4
\end{bmatrix}$$

The answers to this system equation would not be the same, when I solved it by using moore-penrose pseudoinverse. My question is that if we extract a system of equations from this matrix multiplication, we still get the same set of equations as before. And why do we get different answers?

Comment: What do you mean by: the answers to this system equation are not the same??

Comment: Sorry for an unclear statement. I meant that when I solved this matrix equation by using moore-penros pseudoinverse, it did not return the same answer as before.

Comment: The pseudo-inverse are obviously different. But when you solved the equations, you got some different results for $x_i$?

Comment: So you are saying that, if the system is more likely to have repeated equations, it is not safe to use pseudo-inverse in order to solve in least square sense. Am I right?

Comment: I have one more question. What is the implication of putting repeated equations in the system? Does that mean I am weighting each equation?